# Stock Fusion-io ioDrive 2 on HP Proliant DL380p Gen8

Tags: hp-proliant, fusionio

We bought 2 Fusion-io ioDrive 2 PCIe Cards on a very good deal. They are 1.2 TB each.
These cards are the stock Fusion-io Cards, not the HP rebranded ones (the ones with custom HP firmware)

We have tried both cards on 2 different HPe DL380p gen8 servers, but none of them recognises any of the cards. Bios and iLO4 both say that PCIe slots are empty. We have tried different PCIe Slots and even different PCIe Risers. Since the servers don't detect them I can't even check which FW version they are running.

Both DL380p servers have current firmware and ROM with SPP 10.16.

I don't think the ioDrives are DOA, but I suspect there might be some compatibility issue.
Before I return them, I would like to know if someone has tried these cards, but the stock Fusion-io (or Sandisk) on an HPe Gen8 server
Any help or tip will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think the ioDrives are DOA,

Don't assume. check - Put them in a non HP system and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, the cards were DOA.
We returned both of them, and bought 2 HPe branded ones, and they are working great now.